# How exactly are unit cells arranged in a crystal?

Tags: crystal-structure

Does a certain type of compound only contain a single type of unit cell (eg.bcc,fcc,etc) or different type of units cells combine to form a crystal of any compound?

Comment: One compound means one crystal structure mean one unit cell. You don't combine different units cells together.

Comment: Whoever taught you about crystallography has willfully omitted the most basic principle. Can you explain how this happened? It ought to be exposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit cell repeats in all three dimensions. In a perfect crystal, you get exact copies of the contents of the unit cell. The unit cell edges a, b, and c are the translation vectors used to translate the contents of the unit cell in three direction. The unit cell is a construct, the atom arrangement it describes is real.

The content of the unit cell can be simple (just one atom) or complicated (complex structure with thousands of atoms, e.g. a protein).

If the unit cell does not repeat in three dimensions, you don't have a 3D crystal. Instead, you might have an amorphous solid, a quasicrystal, a crystal with defects, or some other non-perfectly ordered structure.

Comment: Ok thank you!. So do the arrangement of these unit cells give rise to voids? for example in NaCl , Na occupy all octahedral voids, How exactly do these voids arise?

Comment: At the beginning, there was the void. Once you place chloride ions in a regular arrangement, only some of the void is occupied by chloride. Connecting the chloride ions in your mind with lines shows octahedrons, the centers of which are maximally distant from the chloride ions and are large enough for sodium ions to fit in. This is an artificial order of making the crystal, of course. Without the sodium ions, the chloride ions would blow apart.